# How to Reload CDA and Mondrian cache in Pentaho CE 4.8?

Tags: caching, mdx, pentaho, mondrian, cda

I'm currently stuck in some performance issue for my Dashboard.

I've created a dashboard in Pentaho Community edition 4.8. For my charts, using the SQL and MDX (Mondrian) queries.

My Problem is that, When I first time open my dashboards after clearing cda and Mondrian cache. It take 50 secs to load. But next time it took less then 10 secs.

I know the method to clear CDA and Mondrain cache automatically.

How to reload the CDA and Mondrian schema cache from back-end (with out opening the dashboard.)?

Please suggest. I'm really getting stuck with that point.

Cheers Guys,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is to schedule the queries using the CDA cache scheduler. You can clear the caches everyday after your ETL runs and schedule the queries to run shortly after.

Take a look at the CDA cache manager from the Tools menu, there's an option to schedule queries. You choose your CDA file, query ID and the parameter values and it'll run the queries at the specified time. Once run, they're stored in the cache.

You can even have parameter values running for each value of a given set. For example, say you have a Country query returning various countries and you want the top 10 customers for each country. You can set the country parameter on your secondary query to be a FOREACH loop. See the CDA documentation, I think they have details about that.

Comment: Could you please share the reference document or sample for schedule the cda cache with parameter?