# Pentaho CDA cache scheduler with Dynamic data

Tags: caching, schema, pentaho, cda

I have a SQL query with 2 Parameters `fromDate` and `toDate` in my dashboard.

A user can select any date range. But still users prefer the date ranges for Last 30 Days, Current Week or Current Month.

The dashboard has some huge data so my sql queries are getting too slow to load the dashboard.

So I've enabled the cda cache to make the dashboard reload faster.  But the data needs to be updated on hourly basis.  So a refresh is required for every hour.

When I clear the cache the dashboard is too slow the first time it is loaded. So I tried to schedule the query with the CDA cache manager.

Refer to this URL : [How to Reload CDA and Mondrian cache in Pentaho CE 4.8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29960048/how-to-reload-cda-and-mondrian-cache-in-pentaho-ce-4-8)

Unfortunately, I am unable to schedule the queries with dynamic parameters.

**How can I schedule the queries with my dynamic parameters?
Also is there any way to do clear cda cache for specific queries?**

Kindly suggest your solution.

Cheers,

Comment: by executing below link in browser you can clear all the CDA catch.
http://localhost:8080/pentaho/plugin/cda/api/clearCache